# how to manage lookups across multiple datasets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, time-complexity

I'm new to working with big data and am trying to replicate some CSV lookups into Pandas code. On smaller datasets, I've been able to get away with nested loops.

The lookups in the CSVs are such that they iterate through all rows in datasheet1, match two fields in datasheet2, and set datasheet 1's row's value if there's a match:

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(
        ISBLANK(
            INDEX(RefTable!$D:$D,MATCH($E6,RefTable!$A:$A,0))
        ),
        "",                                                                                 
        INDEX(RefTable!$D:$D,MATCH($E6,RefTable!$A:$A,0))
    ),
    ""
)
```

When I try to do this in Pandas, it ends up as `O(n^2)` operation, which is becoming quite slow. E.g., Lookup the matching cities of a particular row then set the state:

```
# total loops: 1000x100 = 100,000
for i, row in dataframe1.iterrows(): # 1000 rows
    for j, row2 in dataframe2.iterrows(): # 100 rows
       if row['market_city'] == row2['city']:
                dataframe1.loc[i, 'state'] = row2['state']
```

How can I break this up to something more manageable like `O(n)`?

Comment: using map you can do it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Don't have python installed on this machine to test, but something like:

```
df3 = dataframe1.merge(dataframe2, 
                       left_on = 'market_city', 
                       right_on = 'city', 
                       how='left').drop(['state_x', 'city'], axis=1)
```

The code above will create a new dataframe which is the same as dataframe1, but with the state from dataframe2 when market_city matches city. If that's still not fast enough, `join()` is likely faster.

Worth noting that joining on indexes is faster, so you could set the indexes  before as follows:

```
dataframe1.set_index('market_city', inplace=True)
dataframe2.set_index('city', inplace=True)
```

Comment: `reindexing`, you mean like renaming `market_city` and `city` to both be `city` and merging on `city`?

Comment: `dataframe2[list('city', 'state')]` - `list` takes one parameter. This doesn't create a new `state` column.

Comment: Setting the market_city and city columns to the index in their respective dfs. Check out the reindex docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html . The list thing was a typo. Should be list(('city', 'state')). I'll test different version now and update the code shortly.

Comment: Check the updated answer above. It works, and should be faster, but not sure how fast for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this question is very interesting and sometimes optimization of code is also a fun.

I tried few lines that gave me the result without using for loop.

I have created two datasets as mentioned in your question

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"market_city":["AM","CM","BM","EM","DM"],
                    "state":["ROM","AOM","SOM","DOM","VOM"]})
print(df1)
  market_city state
0          AM   ROM
1          CM   AOM
2          BM   SOM
3          EM   DOM
4          DM   VOM

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"city":["CM","KM","AM"],"state":["ZOM","TOM","KOM"]})
print(df2)
  city state
0   CM   ZOM
1   KM   TOM
2   AM   KOM
```

Now, as we have two dataframes where in we are replacing the `df1` state by `df2` state where ever we see match between market_city of `df1` and city of `df2`

**Code**

```
dct_val = dict(zip(df2['city'], df2.state))
df1['state'] = df1['market_city'].replace(dct_val)

print(df1)
  market_city state
0          AM   KOM
1          CM   ZOM
2          BM    BM
3          EM    EM
4          DM    DM
```